# web2py: customizing form.vars to pass inputs id

Tags: forms, django-forms, customization, web2py

I'm building a web app using web2py for attending employees.

this is the db in the model

```
db.define_table(
    'employee',
     Field('name'),
     format = '%(name)s'
)
db.define_table(
    'attendance',
    Field('employee_id',db.employee),
    Field('attend','boolean'),
    Field('comments','text')
)
```

This is the controller:

```
employeeIDS=db(db.employee).select(db.employee.ALL)
table=[]
for eid in employeeIDS:  
table.append([eid.name,INPUT(_type="checkbox",_name=eid.id,_id=eid.id),INPUT(_type="text",_name="comments",_id=eid.id)])

form=FORM( TABLE(TR("employee name","attended?","comments"),*[TR(*rows) for rows in table]),INPUT(_type="submit",_value="SUBMIT"))    
if form.accepts(request,session):
     response.flash="form accepted"
     print(request.vars)
elif form.errors:
     response.flash="form is invalid"
else:
     response.flash="please fill the form"

return dict(form=form,vars=form.vars)
```

My question is this:
How can I access the id of the attend and comments fields in each row to associate these fields with the related employee. So, when I insert the form.vars to the attendance table, I guarantee that each employee recorded as attendance or absence and the related comments will inserted too.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving each `comments` input the same name, make the names unique, including the record ID as part of the name:

```
INPUT(_type="text", _name="comments_%s" % eid.id)
```

Then you will have `form.vars.comments_1`, `form.vars.comments_2`, etc.

As an aside, note that HTML `id` attributes should be unique, but you are using the value `eid.id` as the `id` attribute of both the checkbox input and the comments input.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better choice is to use [SQLFROM](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#SQLFORM) instead of FORM.

There you can [customize the resulting form in the view](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Custom-forms) right the layout you want to, even with HTML helper for tables, you have already used.

Please have a look at the [signature of the SQLFORM](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators?search=readable#SQLFORM) - it offers a lot options as labels or showid (following the link just scroll down a little).

To exclude a field of being changed or even displayed in the SQLFORM use:

```
db.my_table.a_field.writable = False
db.my_table.a_field.readable = False
```

as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators?search=readable#SQLFORM-grid-signature) - it's the same for SQLFORMS.